Insert Image beside Tabular
I have some issues with Image Inserting. That's the Code part.
\begin{rSection}{Persönliches}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l r }
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz  &  \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=22mm]{Foto_Zugeschnitten (2023).JPG}} \\
Familienstand:  & x &   \\
Adresse:        & y &   \\
                & z & \\
\vspace{1cm}
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection} 

I would like to align the image in the multirow on the right side (Right now the alignment is with the tabular and its quite centered in the PDF). Im not sure how i can realize that. Thanks a lot for the help.

Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can test as it is. So far it contain unknown commands ...

Check out valign from adjustbox [export].  You can also use \raisebox (both to set the baseline and overlap the other rows).

I suppose you mean the image should go to the righthand side of the paper. I have two solutions:

Use tabularx to fill out the right column and add \hfill to push the image right
Put the image outside the tabular; but then you may have to do the vertical adjustment of the image and the table.

(By the way, I find the \vspace{1cm} inside the tabular a bit strange. I have left it out to get better spacing in the example. I think you would normally put that after the tabular.)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Original:

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l r }
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz  &  \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image}} \\
Familienstand:  & x &   \\
Adresse:        & y &   \\
                & z & \\
\end{tabular}

with tabularx:

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l >{\hfill}X @{}}
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz  &  \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image}} \\
Familienstand:  & x &   \\
Adresse:        & y &   \\
                & z & \\
\end{tabularx}

Outside of tabular, with default vertical adjustment of image (=bottom)

\begin{tabular}[b]{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz \\
Familienstand:  & x   \\
Adresse:        & y   \\
                & z   \\
\end{tabular} \hfill \includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image}

Outside of tabular, use \texttt{valign=t} from package adjustbox for top alignment

\begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz \\
Familienstand:  & x   \\
Adresse:        & y   \\
                & z   \\
\end{tabular} \hfill \includegraphics[width=22mm,valign=t]{example-image}

\end{document}



You don't need \multirow, which actually makes things more complicated.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % usual in a CV

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{2em}} l }
Geburtsdatum:   & xyz \\
Familienstand:  & x   \\
Adresse:        & y   \\
                & z   \\
\end{tabular}%
\includegraphics[width=22mm,valign=t]{example-image-9x16}\par
\vspace{2ex}

Some text follows

\end{document}


